# Trying to create a random number generator with user input for parameters

Tags: java

Whenever I attempt to do this, I get some weird numbers. If I input 10, I get 1.012....... and if I input 8 I get 64359...
    import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

```
class proyecto{
public static void main(String[]args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random numb = new Random();
    int numbe;
    int number;
    numbe = input.nextInt();
    numbe = numb.nextInt();

    System.out.println(numb.nextInt());

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see where the user input affects the outcome of the random number generator.

Comment: it gives the parameters for the the generator like if they input 10, it'll generate numbers 0-10

Comment: No, it really doesn't.  Is that your question, how to get random number in a range?

Comment: You assign the scanner value to numbe then you assign a single random to numbe  and then it returns a 2nd random number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the rewrite for this class.

```
import java.util.Random;

class proyecto{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        Random numb = new Random();
        if(args.length>0){
            System.out.println(numb.nextInt(Integer.parseInt(args[0].toString()));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Takes the arguments passed to the main class, converts it to a string, and converts the string to an integer. Uses that integer to restrict the random number generator output from 0 to the number specified. When you use the scanner, you need to type the numbers each time the routine is run in real-time. Using the arguments allowes it to be called from another proces.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Test it, try it, and if it works, please do me the honor of an approved answer. The laborer is worthy of his hire.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys

```
class proyecto{
public static void main(String[]args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random numb = new Random();
    int numbe;
    int number;
    numbe = numb.nextInt(input.nextInt());

    System.out.println(numbe);
}
}
```